# Zip files from web urls without storing on a local disk

Tags: zip

I have a list of http urls
http://host.com/url1
http://host.com/url2
http://host.com/url3

Each url is pointed to some file

Is there a way to compress all that files to single zip archive without downloading files locally?
I don't see a way to do this with linux zip command. It allows to have list of files, but not list of urls

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using ksh eg.

```
(
  for URL in http://host.com/url1 http://host.com/url2 http://host.com/url3
  do
    wget -O - -q "$URL"
  done
) | gzip -c > mysingle.zip
```

You now have all data zipped into one file, but not really an archive: you can't extract one of the files, you'd need to add a separator in the loop.

Comment: Interesting. But even if I added a separator, what would the file names inside the ZIP archive be?

Comment: @Marcel: it's NOT an archive, there are no filenames inside the zip, it is a compressed data stream.